# How to connect remote mongo db with android application

Tags: android, mongodb

I want to make a connection between my android app and mongodb. here is my code below:

```
    try {
        //MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("10.1.1.1", 27017);//new MongoClient("mongodb://10.1.1.1:27017");
        String dbURI = "mongodb://192.168.1.2:27017";
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(dbURI));

        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("TestDatabase");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DBName = " + db.getName());

        Set<String> collections = db.getCollectionNames();
        for (String colName : collections) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "colName = " + colName);
            System.out.println("\t + Collection: " + colName);
        }

        mongoClient.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "exceptionMongo = " + e);
    }
```

and gradle seems like this

```
compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.13.2'
```

and manifest file is like

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Tell me please, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: It's not a common practice to directly connect to a database from your android app. I would suggest you build a little API, which accesses the database and delivers the results to your app.

Comment: any breif tutorial is available to build api? @babadaba

Comment: If you are good with php have a look at the symfony framework. If you prefer Javascript you can try node.js with express: http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/10/01/creating-a-restful-api-tutorial-with-nodejs-and-mongodb/. If you prefer Java try the spring framework

Comment: Connect to DB via user app? It's very, very bad. In this case any user can do everything with database, even drop it! You have to write a server, which will get requests from app and respond.